# Check a string contain particular substring or not

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

Check a string contain particular substring or not.

when a user register I want to check entered emailid domain match with my predefined emailid or not(eg @gmail.com ,@outlook.com etc).

Comment: How about just using `indexOf` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using **regular expressions** is probably the best way.

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /@gmail.com$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions are versatile one you can make custom changes as per requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use **indexOf** javascript method, or use regular expression:

```
var mail = "foo@gmail.com";
var domain = "foo";
if(mail.indexOf(domain) > -1) {
  console.log("domain valid");
} else {
  console.log("domain not valid");
}
```

So you can have your custom function:

```
/* global domain array */
var domains = new Array("gmail.com", "outlook.com", ...);

var checkDomain(mail) {
   for(var i = 0; i != domains.length; ++i) {
      if(mail.indexOf(domains[i]) > -1) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```